# Dynamic Programming sum dice

Tags: python

I have the following task: You have w amount of dice with possiblities from 1-6. For a given number S, calculate the amount of possibilities the dice can fall, so the their sum is equal to S.

For example: Amount(w, S) with w = 2, S = 7 => Amount(2, 7) = 6

Step 1 was to create a simple recursive algorithm that calculates the problem, which I did (it works):

```
def Amount(w, S):
    amount = 0
    if w == 0 and S == 0:
        amount = 1
    elif w == 0 and S > 0:
        amount = 0
    elif S < 0:
        amount = 0
    else:
        for number in range(1,7):
            subproblem = S - number
            amount = amount + Amount(w-1, subproblem) 

        
    return amount
```

now my problem is with correctly storing the already calculated data in an 2D-array to speed up the calculation.

I tried upgrading the code as follows:

```
memo = [[-1] * (S+1)] * (w+1) #create a 2-D array large enough to store the data (default = -1)

def AmountOptimized(w, S):
    amount = 0

    if memo[w][S] != -1: #if a value has already been calculated, use it
       return memo[w][S]
    
    if w == 0 and S == 0:
        amount = 1
    elif w == 0 and S > 0:
        amount = 0
    elif S < 0:
        amount = 0
    else:
        for number in range(1,7):
            subproblem = S - number
            amount = amount + AmountOptimized(w-1, subproblem)
            
    memo[w][S] = amount #when the calculation is done, store it

    return amount
```

I dont really understand what has gone wrong at this point, the outputs are wrong.

Comment: Hint: `memo = [[-1] * (S+1)] * (w+1)` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: It looks like your `memo` is not what you think it is. You probably want: `memo = [[-1] * (S+1) for _ in range(w+1)]`

Comment: Wow, i thought i was going crazy. Tyvm!